# Highchart: exact distance between ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How to find out the exact distance or set an exact distance (to pixel) between two ticks on x-axis with Highchart?

I have used tickPixelInterval, it does not seem to set the exact distance between two ticks on an axis.

Code for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/e0qxfLtt/21/

```
$(function drawCharts() {
  var chartData = [100, 120, 120, 140, 110, 110];
  var index = 1;
  $('#b').click(function() {
    var buttonB = document.getElementById('b');
    buttonB.disabled = true;
    if (index < chartData.length) {
      var x = index, // current time
        y = chartData[index];
      $('#container').highcharts().series[0].setData([chartData[index - 1]]);
      $('#container').highcharts().series[0].addPoint([chartData[index]]);

      setTimeout(function() {
        if (index === 1) {
          $('#container1').highcharts().series[0].addPoint([0, chartData[0]]);
        }
        $('#container1').highcharts().series[0].addPoint([x, y]);
        index++;
      }, 2000);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      buttonB.disabled = false;
    }, 3000);

  })
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container1',
        type: 'line',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
          load: function() {
            series = this.series[0];
          },
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        startOnTick: true,
        tickPixelInterval: 40,
        min: 0,
        max: 10
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 200
      },
      plotOptions: {
        line: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        series: {
          animation: {
            duration: 1000
          }
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + 'GE';
        }
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        name: '',
        data: []
      }]
    });
    var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
        animation: Highcharts.svg ? {
          duration: 2000
        } : false, // don't animate in old IE                marginRight: 10,
        events: {
          load: function() {
            series = this.series[0];
          },
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        startOnTick: true,
        tickPixelInterval: 80,
        categories: ['a', 'b'],
        min: 0,
        max: 1
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 200
      },
      plotOptions: {
        line: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        series: {
          animation: {
            duration: 2000
          }
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        }
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        name: '',
        data: []
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Comment: For example, this one? http://jsfiddle.net/e0qxfLtt/21/

Comment: **tickPixelInterval**, per the docs: *"this option sets the approximate pixel interval of the tick marks"* Think of it as a guideline, and the library chooses the best logical interval accordingly. To get more specific, you can use the **tickPositions** property, which allows you to set the specific axis values, or the **tickPositioner** function, which allows you to define a custom callback function to place the ticks.  Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Given the update, and posted fiddle: if you want to be able to control the exact pixel distance, and also maintain logical number as in your fiddle (1,2,3, etc. ...), you need to control the size of your chart and plot area, in conjunction with the number of ticks, rather than trying to control the axis tick settings.

Comment: @jibrggs Thank you for your answer. What I want to do is to make sure that the distance between two ticks in the left chart is the same as the distance between two ticks in the right chart. Is there any way to do it other than trial and error plus measuring across the screen with a ruler?

Comment: The categories type of xAxis require to use equal numbers, so tickPixelInterval does not work as you expect (returns not equal number). You can try to extract information about distance from categories chart and apply into number. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q9vxc9uf/

Comment: @Aqqqq yes, as I said - set the number of ticks that you will have; control the width of your plot area by setting the width of the chart, and setting the left and right margins. Set them in a way that results in the desired number of pixels per tick.

Comment: Unrelated to the question posted, but I am very curious what your use case for this overall chart set up is - do you mind elaborating on what you're doing?

Comment: @jlbriggs Thanks for the answer. I am writing something for an experiment, in which some variables should be kept constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the width of your chart, and control the width of your plot area using the margin settings, and you know how many ticks you are going to have in each chart, this is a simple matter.

So,  chart 1:

```
width: 200,
margin: [10,25,50,75]
```

Two slots, each 50 pixels wide

Chart 2:

```
width: 600,
margin: [10,25,50,75]
```

10 slots, each 50 pixels wide.

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/k8r4s890/

Output:

[image: screenshot]