# How to scale Highcharts Line graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am trying to achieve divisions measurement on Y axis and X axis should be equal. Means whatever user see it'll be looks like blocks of same measurement.

Twist comes here,both X and Y axis belongs to two different measurement unit. 
X Axis define Time and Y Axis define Voltage.

[image]

Images shows two grids on X Axis, one is minor grid and other is major grid. 
For minor grid i'm using plotLines and Major grid i'm using tickInterval.

**Now i want same px partitions(Major / Minor) on Y Axis. Whenever X and Y minor grid line intersect, it'll form square**
Is there any way in Highcharts to Scale X and Y axis.?

*Your help will be highly appreciated.!*

Comment: Can you paste your code here or recreate the problem on jsfiddle? The solution might differ depends on some factors, e.g. do you have static width/height of the chart, do you know min/max of your data - so you can set min/max in options? There is no configurable option for setting exact tick pixel interval, but some good answers can be posted if you share the code, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898218/highchart-exact-distance-between-ticks

Comment: @morganfree Thanks ! It's Done !